# Blazor. How to capture mouse in onmousemove event?

Tags: mouseevent, dom-events, blazor, capture

How to capture mouse in `onmousemove` event in Blazor like `UIElement.CaptureMouse()` in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... in Blazor like UIElement.CaptureMouse()

The closest match would be [`Element.setPointerCapture()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture)

In order to use it you will need to get an ElementReference in Blazor with `@ref` and a JS method to invoke setPointerCapture on it. You need to pass a pointerId that you get from PointerEventArgs.

Do not use the Mouse* related events/methods, they are more or less deprecated in JS.

So you can start with something like:

```
 <div @ref="myTarget" @onpointerdown="StartCapture">  ... </div>

@code{    
    ElementReference myTarget;

    async Task StartCapture(PointerEventArgs args)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("myJsFunctions.capturePointer",
                 myTarget, args.PointerId);
    }    
}
```